# How to map spring mvc reactive exception advice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

How can i implement a custom Advice for reactive errors ? 
Like in the case above, it will return 200, but should be 500 or other custom error.

```
@GetMapping("/error")
public Completable completableDaoError() {
    return Completable.error(new Exception());
}
```

Searching the documentation i found WebExceptionHandler and ResponseStatusExceptionHandler (default implementation) but i can't mapping one on my on.

In the search they use just map as:

```
@Component 
@Order(-2)
class RestWebExceptionHandler implements WebExceptionHandler {
}
```

But this doesn't work.
How can i do this in spring mvc ? I'm not using spring boot just web-mvc and webflux.

Comment: It is 200 because you are handling the Exception and the server is not blowing up and left in a bad state.  If you can handle the error and return a message to the user something bad happened (200 response), that is much preferred over letting a error bubble all the way up and be a 500 server error.

Comment: You say treat in the controller and avoid it getting up ?
Yeahh... make sense, this will work, i'm trying to make a more generic treatment, so i raise the exception and the advisor will do the job, like we do in the ControllerAdvice.
But this will work too

Comment: The code snippets that you provided are not enough to figure out what's happening. Could you show your pom.xml/build.gradle? Can you show the implementation of your RestWebExceptionHandler and controller (including package names)? How are you setting up and starting your app and the spring context?